# The use of the word "about" to qualify a date

Tags: word-usage, dates

> Minutes and second hands were put on some clocks in (about) 1697.

Can I use "about" before 1697 in the given sentence?

Answer (score 1):

If it was within that year, then use *in*.

If approximately that year or near to that year, then you can use *around* or *about*.

Comment: In the second case, *around* sounds most natural to me.